# Unable to access a function which is sent as a props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6

I have a react server running and my purpose is to `console log` some data whenever there is any changes in check box.

I have two `jsx` file first one `Todo.jsx` is mapping the data and sending it to other jsx file `Option.jsx` which returns a JSX component and finally I am using the Todo.jsx file to display components in my app.

**Todo.jsx**

```
import Option from "./Option";
const Obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "A Sample data",
    user: "XYZ"
  },
.
.
.  // data objects
];
// data of the todo list 

class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      components : Obj
    }
    this.Change =  this.Change.bind(this)
    
  }
Change(id){                   // the function that I am passing as props
    console.log("Changed",id)    
  }
  
  render(){
    var Components = this.state.components.map(function (obj) {
      return <Option key={obj.id} name={obj.name} user={obj.user} Change = {this.Change} />;
    });
    return (<div>{Components}</div>)
  }
  
}

export default Todo;
```

**Option.jsx**

Only has a function which returns a component

```
function Option (props) {
  
    return (
      <div
        className="m-todo"
        style={{ backgroundColor: props.user ? "orangeRed" : "green" }}
      >
        <p style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }}>
          <input type="checkbox"  onChange={()=>{props.Change(props.id)}}></input> {props.name}:
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p >{props.user}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I am not able to understand what I am missing out. Function is never recognized and when I am trying to `console.log(props)`  it shows me `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue is because of the `scope` of `this` keyword and the way called is used while mapping over you data.

In your `Todo` component when you are mapping over you are using the callback as normal `ES5` function, due to this the `scope is lost` and `Change` handler function is passed as `undefined`. Try this: )

```
  render() {
    var Components = this.state.components.map((obj) => {
      return (
        <Option
          key={obj.id}
          name={obj.name}
          user={obj.user}
          change={this.change}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div>{Components}</div>;
  }
```

**FULL CODE:** https://codesandbox.io/s/here-i-am-qvx3h?file=/src/App.js:514-789

**UPDATE:** Another solution would be using ES6 arrow function as your `Change` handler method :)

**NOTE:** It's best practice to use your function names as lower case. Like I have done in my code :) Thanks !!!

Comment: Using this code, don't forget to rewrite function names to lowercase in your "Option" component as well. Tested locally working for me.

Comment: Have done this already :) Thanks :) Let me check again whether anywhere I missed it. Overall I did it

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Is there any changes in how function functions work in es5 vs es6. All i have heard is that you get a cool and simple way to write when you use arrow functions. Your code worked for me. But can you please tell me a bit more deeply about the things happening behind the scenes or even some reference will be helpful! Thank you

Comment: Let me answer this question `Is there any changes in how function functions work in es5 vs es6` . The answer is yes, A lot of changes in fact.

Comment: In ES6 arrow function, if you are using the `this` keyword. The scope of `this` is the outer `execution context`,

Comment: When You were have used `this.change = this.change.bind()`, Do you know why? To bind the scope of `this` with the Component Todo. Otherwise `this.setState()` once used inside the function  would not have worked or in your case `this.change()`.

Comment: To help yourself more go through these articles : https://medium.com/@User3141592/react-gotchas-and-best-practices-2d47fd67dd22    and this https://medium.com/@joespinelli_6190/using-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-in-react-5d7402eec64

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not provided "id":

```
<Option key={obj.id} name={obj.name} user={obj.user} id={name={obj.id}} Change = {this.Change} />;
```

Comment: @Do van Thang: That's a secondary  thing. The prop `Change` function is passed as `undefined` to the child component And that's where the problem is :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like

```
Change = (id) => {                   // the function that I am passing as props
  console.log("Changed",id)    
}
```